# yhat ggplot facet_wrap type error

Tags: python, ggplot2, facet-wrap, python-ggplot

I have a pandas `dataframe` that I read in via txt file:

```
training = pd.read_csv('training_data.txt')
```

These are the columns:

```
>> print training.columns.values`  
['segment' 'cookie_id' 'num_visits' 'num_page_views']
```

I'm interested in a graph that shows the density of `num_page_views` by segment, like so:

```
plot = ggplot(training, aes(x='num_visits')) + geom_density()
        + xlim(0,20) + facet_wrap( ~ 'segment')  
print plot
```

And it gives the following **error**:

> TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in ()
>         1 
>   ----> 2 plot = ggplot(training, aes(x='num_visits')) + geom_density() +xlim(0,20) +facet_wrap( ~ 'segment')
>         3 print plot
>
> TypeError: bad operand type for unary ~: 'str'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In yhat ggplot, the facet option does not take a "~". You can find this is in the [documentation](http://blog.yhat.com/posts/ggplot-for-python.html) (copied here for convenience):

```
import pandas as pd

meat_lng = pd.melt(meat, id_vars=['date'])

p = ggplot(aes(x='date', y='value'), data=meat_lng)
p + geom_point() + \
    stat_smooth(colour="red") + \
    facet_wrap("variable")

p + geom_hist() + facet_wrap("color")

p = ggplot(diamonds, aes(x='price'))
p + geom_density() + \
    facet_grid("cut", "clarity")

p = ggplot(diamonds, aes(x='carat', y='price'))
p + geom_point(alpha=0.25) + \
    facet_grid("cut", "clarity")
```

Comment: I see an example, but no documentation. You answer says, "You can find this is in the documentation (copied here for convenience):"